# Android MPAndroidChart LineChart how to Ignore ViewPager touch gestures completely?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, linechart

I am trying to make the linechart from mpandroidchart ignore the fragmentviewpager and only move the linechart and not the viewpager when touching the view. My question is how can I archive this?

I found this solution but dont know how to implement it Maybee you guys can help me understand how to implement it?
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1885#issuecomment-267568663

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

```
int mNumberOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumberOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumberOfTabs = NumberOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            IncomeOutcomeOverviewFragment incomeOutcomeOverviewFragment = new IncomeOutcomeOverviewFragment();
            return incomeOutcomeOverviewFragment;
        case 1:
            IncomeFragment incomeFragment = new IncomeFragment();
            return incomeFragment;
        case 2:
            OutcomeFragment outcomeFragment = new OutcomeFragment();
            return outcomeFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumberOfTabs;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is nor swipeable view pager for that you have to create custom view pager like this

**UPDATE** changes suggested by @anomynous

```
 public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

        boolean enabled = false;

        public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setMyScroller();
        }

        public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setMyScroller();
        }

        @Override

        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (this.enabled) {
                return false;
            }
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);

        }

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (this.enabled) {
                return false;
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);

        }

        //down one is added for smooth scrolling

        private void setMyScroller() {
            try {
                Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
                Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
                scroller.setAccessible(true);
                scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
            public MyScroller(Context context) {
                super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
            }

            @Override
            public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
                super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
            }
        }

        public void setPagingDisabled(boolean enabled) {
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }
    }

Then on my linechart I used onChartGestureStart and onChartGestureEnd to enable or disable the pageview:

    @Override
        public void onChartGestureStart(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
            nonSwipeableViewPager.setPagingDisabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChartGestureEnd(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
            nonSwipeableViewPager.setPagingDisabled(false);
        }
```

replace default viewpager with custom one in xml

Comment: does this also work with FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: post your  xml file in which you have used viewpager

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bvWLT0Rv if you change your aswer to this I accept it as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

You need you to disable touch for your chart, you can use this code,

```
chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
```

Comment: the viewpager still gets activated when I swipe on the linechart with settouchenabled

Comment: What do you want to disable? Viewpager touch or chart's touch?

Comment: I want to disable the viewpager touch only when you touch the chart